# swap "meta" and "Ctrl" for Octave with Qt on macOS

Tags: macos, qt, keyboard-shortcuts, octave, keymapping

I have installed Octave on Mac, with the Qt frontend. When I'm editing a file in the editor, I can't find any key mapping to "go to end of this line" or to "go to beginning of this line". I tried <kbd>End</kbd> and <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd>, but neither worked. I looked into "Settings -> Shortcuts" but didn't find such an action for me to map a key to.

FYI, I'm with latest El Capitan, latest Octave.

#### update

I found that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> does the trick, but I want to use that to switch between workspaces. How can I swap "meta" and "Ctrl" key on Octave Qt? Originally it maps <kbd>⌃</kbd> to "meta" and <kbd>⌘</kbd> to "Ctrl", which is really confusing. In addition, "Ctrl" (<kbd>⌘</kbd>) is not used by any keyboard shortcut in Octave Qt.

Comment: This question may also fit [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: This question is unrelated to octave. Such key-bindings are specific to the Mac operating system.

Comment: I suspect it to be related to some Qt settings. Maybe Qt thinks this is good for cross-platform? I see that some user likes "Ctrl everywhere" but I would prefer "follow the system".